# Unexpected token export from 4 different export ways

Tags: node.js, cors, export

My environment, Node.js is at v11.10.1 & npm is 6.9.0.

The code that fails in app.js.

```
const cors = require("./config/cors");
```

Here is config/cors.js

```
const cors = (req, res, next) => {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin,X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
};

//export default cors;
//export {cors as default}
//export {cors};
//module.exports = cors;
//module.exports = { cors }
module.exports = { cors: cors }
```

I have tried six different ways of exporting the cors module but all attempts fail with the same error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
module.exports = { cors: cors }
```

The reason for that being you must export an object and cors is simply a function so you can put the function inside an object and export it.

Or the shorthand

```
module.exports = { cors }
```

However, if you want something fancier I suggest looking into [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) which will allow you to do:

```
export default cors
```

This is a newer syntax not yet officially supported by node but can be used with some setup tools such as esm or webpack

Comment: Hi Pedro, 
I tried your suggestion and got the same error. I also edited my initial question for extra context.

Comment: I have just tested it with this config https://gist.github.com/pedsm/aa378942e243ea1ed69a6362ef68f400 and it seems to be working just fine on node 11. If you create the two files in this gist and run the main.js you should see the function being imported